# регулярные выражение js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как нужно написать регулярные выражение что бы получилось

`/sv/nano-gps-tracker-sv` было

`nano-gps-tracker-sv это динамическое значение.`

`sv/` стало

Comment: так может вам не регулярка нужна а `indexOf` по значению `sv/`?

Comment: Забыл указать это sv/ это тоже динамическое значение, спасибо.

Comment: Так может вам нужен `indexOf` по этому самому динамическому значению?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const str = '/sv/nano-gps-tracker-sv';

const result = /-(\w+)\/?$/.test(str) && RegExp.$1;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, то поставьте пожалуйста "галочку"